# Matlab slow parallel processing with distributed arrays

Tags: parallel-processing, distributed, distributed-computing, matlab

I am new to using distributed and codistributed arrays in matlab. The parallel code I have produced works, but is much slower than the serial version and I have no idea why. The code examples below compute the eigenvalues of hessian matrices from volumetic data.

Serial version:

```
S = size(D);
Dsmt=imgaussian(D,2,20);
[fx, fy, fz] = gradient(Dsmt);
DHess = zeros([3 3 S(1) S(2) S(3)]);
[DHess(1,1,:,:,:), DHess(1,2,:,:,:), DHess(1,3,:,:,:)] = gradient(fx);
[DHess(2,1,:,:,:), DHess(2,2,:,:,:), DHess(2,3,:,:,:)] = gradient(fy);
[DHess(3,1,:,:,:), DHess(3,2,:,:,:), DHess(3,3,:,:,:)] = gradient(fz);

d = zeros([3 S(1) S(2) S(3)]);
for i = 1 : S(1)
    fprintf('Slice %d out of %d\n', i, S(1));
    for ii = 1 : S(2)
        for iii = 1 : S(3)
            d(:,i,ii,iii) = eig(squeeze(DHess(:,:,i,ii,iii)));
        end
    end
end
```

Parallel version:

```
S = size(D);
Dsmt=imgaussian(D,2,20);
[fx, fy, fz] = gradient(Dsmt);
DHess = zeros([3 3 S(1) S(2) S(3)]);
[DHess(1,1,:,:,:), DHess(1,2,:,:,:), DHess(1,3,:,:,:)] = gradient(fx);
[DHess(2,1,:,:,:), DHess(2,2,:,:,:), DHess(2,3,:,:,:)] = gradient(fy);
[DHess(3,1,:,:,:), DHess(3,2,:,:,:), DHess(3,3,:,:,:)] = gradient(fz);
CDHess = distributed(DHess);
spmd  
    d = zeros([3 S(1) S(2) S(3)], codistributor('1d',4));
    for i = 1 : S(1)
        fprintf('Slice %d out of %d\n', i, S(1));
        for ii = 1 : S(2)
            for iii = drange(1 : S(3))
                d(:,i,ii,iii) = eig(squeeze(CDHess(:,:,i,ii,iii)));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

If someone could shed some light on the issue I would be very grateful

Comment: How long does a single iteration take?

Comment: are you opening your matlabpool?

Comment: @Jonas A single iteration (over variable i) on the serial version takes around 1.7 seconds. A single iteration on the parallel version does not complete in over 5 minutes at which point I have terminated the execution.

Comment: @Rasman Yes, I forgot to mention I am opening the matlabpool using the 'local' profile with 6 labs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a re-written version of your code. I have split the work over the outer-most loop, not as in your case - the inner-most loop. I have also explicitly allocated local parts of the `d` result vector, and the local part of the Hessian matrix.

In your code you rely on `drange` to split the work, and you access the distributed arrays directly to avoid extracting the local part. Admittedly, it should not result in such a great slowdown if MATLAB did everything correctly. The bottom line is, I don't know why your code is so slow - most likely because MATLAB does some remote data accessing despite the fact that you distributed your matrices.

Anyway, the below code runs and gives pretty good speedup on my computer using 4 labs. I have generated synthetic random input data to have something to work on. Have a look at the comments. If something is unclear, I can elaborate later.

```
clear all;

D = rand(512, 512, 3);
S = size(D);
[fx, fy, fz] = gradient(D);

% this part could also be parallelized - at least a bit.
tic;
DHess = zeros([3 3 S(1) S(2) S(3)]);
[DHess(1,1,:,:,:), DHess(1,2,:,:,:), DHess(1,3,:,:,:)] = gradient(fx);
[DHess(2,1,:,:,:), DHess(2,2,:,:,:), DHess(2,3,:,:,:)] = gradient(fy);
[DHess(3,1,:,:,:), DHess(3,2,:,:,:), DHess(3,3,:,:,:)] = gradient(fz);
toc

% your sequential implementation
d = zeros([3, S(1) S(2) S(3)]);
disp('sequential')
tic
for i = 1 : S(1)
    for ii = 1 : S(2)
        for iii = 1 : S(3)
            d(:,i,ii,iii) = eig(squeeze(DHess(:,:,i,ii,iii)));
        end
    end
end
toc

% my parallel implementation
disp('parallel')
tic
spmd
    % just for information
    disp(['lab ' num2str(labindex)]);

    % distribute the input data along the third dimension
    % This is the dimension of the outer-most loop, hence this is where we
    % want to parallelize!
    DHess_dist  = codistributed(DHess, codistributor1d(3));
    DHess_local = getLocalPart(DHess_dist);

    % create an output data distribution - 
    % note that this time we split along the second dimension
    codist = codistributor1d(2, codistributor1d.unsetPartition, [3, S(1) S(2) S(3)]);
    localSize = [3 codist.Partition(labindex) S(2) S(3)];

    % allocate local part of the output array d
    d_local = zeros(localSize);

    % your ordinary loop, BUT! the outermost loop is split amongst the
    % threads explicitly, using local indexing. In the loop only local parts
    % of matrix d and DHess are accessed
    for i = 1:size(d_local,2)
        for ii = 1 : S(2)
            for iii = 1 : S(3)
                d_local(:,i,ii,iii) = eig(squeeze(DHess_local(:,:,i,ii,iii)));
            end
        end
    end

    % assemble local results to a codistributed matrix
    d_dist = codistributed.build(d_local, codist);
end
toc

isequal(d, d_dist)
```

And the output

```
Elapsed time is 0.364255 seconds.
sequential
Elapsed time is 33.498985 seconds.
parallel
Lab 1: 
  lab 1
Lab 2: 
  lab 2
Lab 3: 
  lab 3
Lab 4: 
  lab 4
Elapsed time is 9.445856 seconds.

ans =

     1
```

**Edit** I have checked the performance on a reshaped matrix `DHess=[3x3xN]`. The performance is not much better (10%), so it is not substantial. But maybe you can implement the `eig` a bit differently? After all, those are `3x3` matrices you are dealing with.

Comment: It's great that you have taken the time to provide this example as I will be able to use these ideas with many future projects. A couple of questions:  I used 'drange' in my code, what is the purpose of this if you have to use 'getLocalPart'.  Using your code I am getting an error: 'Error using distcompserialize
Error during serialization' at the line    DHess_dist  = codistributed(DHess, codistributor1d(3));  The size of my input D is around 512x512x200, perhaps the size is an issue; although it seems it should not matter how big the array is, as this is a main purpose of parallel processing

Comment: I should also state that D is a double.

Comment: @Hampycalc I am sorry, I have obviously missed the fact that you used `drange`. I will edit my answer - you did divide your work after all. My bad.

Comment: @Hampycalc I have tried the code for other dimensions and it does not complain. `D` in my code is also of type `double`, so no problem there. I *do not* use `drange` and extract the local parts of my matrices to explicitly operate only on local data. In your case you relied on MATLAB to do the work splitting, which apparently went rather bad.

Comment: Yes, I will do as you have advised and extract local parts first in the future. I am still getting the error as before, but I shall search elsewhere for a solution as you have already answered my original question. Oddly I am using a x64 system with >50GB RAM and Matlab 2012a x64, so would be surprised if it is a memory issue. Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Hampycalc Can you try with a smaller system size? Do you also get an error then? Or does the code run correctly? I actually feel I have not really answered your question :) I wrote a code that scales, but I **do not know** why your code does so badly. It must be something with MATLAB. I always try to use local data in such situations, because I've had bad experience with programs accessing distributed arrays, like yours.

Comment: Decreasing the size of the input variable 'D' does results in the program running correctly and ~NOOFCORES times faster than the serial version. After a bit of searching, I have found there is a serialization limit of 2GB for communications between client and workers. Therefore when D >250Mb and therefore DHess >2GB, the serialization error occurs. This seems a pretty major drawback of the parallel processing functionality. I am installing v2012b to see if the problem has been resolved.

Comment: Just to follow up, Matlab v2012b does not change this issue. It seems it is only possible to serialise data of <=2GB

Comment: @Hampycalc Well, what you could do is split your problem into smaller chunks and iterate. Since you problem does not require any communication, this is rather trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify where you've opened your matlabpool, and that will be the main factor determining what speedup you get.

If you are using the 'local' scheduler, then there is often no benefit to using distributed arrays. In particular, if the time-consuming operations are multithreaded in MATLAB already, then they will almost certainly slow down when using the local scheduler since the matlabpool workers run in single-threaded mode.

If you are using some other scheduler with the workers on a separate machine then you might be able to get speedup, but that depends on what you're doing. There's an example here http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/distcomp/paralleldemo_backslash_bench.html which shows some benchmarks of MATLAB's `\` operator.

Finally, it's worth noting that indexing distributed arrays is unfortunately rather slow, especially compared to MATLAB's built-in indexing. If you can extract the 'local part' of your codistributed arrays inside the spmd block and work exclusively with those, that might also help.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention I am opening the matlabpool using the 'local' profile with 6 labs, however a single iteration is around 1.7 seconds using the serial version, and the parallel version does not complete a single iteration in over 5 minutes.

Comment: The operation (eig) itself is not multithreaded, and it doesn't need to be as the matrix taken as input is only 3x3. However it would benefit by being able to assign each outer or inner loop to a separate core. I will attempt your suggested idea about extracting the 'local part' and report back.